# Create Excel supported XML in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, image, excel

I want to create Excel supported xml file in iPhone. How to embed the image in the xml file and the image is present in my resource folder? I want to attach this xml file in mail and send to others. Others should be be able to open the xml file as Excel sheet and see the text and images.

I followed [this](http://mobile.experts-exchange.com/A_4575.html) link for creating xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your example shows old xml Excel format used in Office 2003. However default double-click will, in most cases, open file in XML associated app, not in Excel. "Real" Excel 2007+ "xlsx" format is a ZIP archive with a set of xml files inside. If your excel file is relatively small and simple then I suggest you to use following approach:

1. Create a template Excel file with your desired content;
2. Extract content of the file, and study it. That you need is repeating pattern of the rows with your data. You can search xml files for your data values to easily locate that you need;
3. Locate and study repeating pattern with data;
4. Create a template XML file to store your data (you can use some placeholder mark there to put data);
5. Then, to create a new Excel file, just fill template XML file with data via string manipulation (as in your example) and put it into your template XLSX file (manupulate it as with zip archive), add additional files into Excel file if requred (images).

Comment: For example, you have found that data you need to write is stored in sheet1.xml file of XLSX file. Create a template from that "sheet1.xml" file, like: <static data> <your data would be here> <static data>. Then generate <your data would be here> part as in your link (using kwnoledge gained at step 2). Create final file by pasting it into template "sheet1.xml" file. Now replace/add "sheet1.xml" file in final XLSX template file. So you need two templates: one XML file with data, and XLSX container file.